# Using the git api to list get unmerged as opposed to merged?

Tags: git, github, github-api

using the github api is there a way to get the unmerged   files  ?  I know there is   methods for  GetAll and   GetMerged but as it stands they return   large amounts of data and  getting the diff between the two is computationally expensive  !  Thanks for any help  :D

Comment: I assume this is github rather than git ?

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion will edit now

Comment: You mean is there a way to compare two branches to find out what's different?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply are looking for a way to discern the difference between two branches you can use the [Repository > Commits > Compare two commits](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits) part of the API. In the hash returned to you, you simply need to grab the list of files and you'll have your files which were changed.

Comment: unfortunately it is not that simple as i need the  json objects representing the unmerged commits  over many different forks , I also need the  commits which are in pull requests but these are easily gotten !

Comment: I'm not entirely certain you can do comparisons across forks with the API, but I'll look into it tonight.

Comment: thank you it would be very much appreciated , i continue to do the same myself